# Search from multiple data source ( json)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am searching for a string from multiple data source

below is the snippet. Use case :

> 1. Search term: `sample hybrid`
> 2. Expected behaviour: `It should compare each word within each data source and return the respective object in "searchResult['first']" & "searchResult['second']".
>      i.e 'sample' should be searched across 2 data sources and return respective object and same should be for word 'hybrid'.

I am doing something wrong and getting an empty object.

```js
var dataSource1 = [{
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001",
  "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
  "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
  "quantity": 261,
  "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002",
  "product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
  "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
  "quantity": 292,
  "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003",

  "product_name": "Sample HBr",
  "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
  "quantity": 211,
  "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}];

var dataSource2 = [{
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000021",
  "product_name": "Hybrid product",
  "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
  "quantity": 261,
  "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000022",
 
  "product_name": "Mountain Sample Juniperus ashei",
  "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
  "quantity": 292,
  "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000033",
  
  "product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
  "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
  "quantity": 211,
  "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}];

const searchCriteria = 'sample hybrid';
const searchResult = [];
function compareEachWord(str, searchCriteria) {
  var word = searchCriteria.split(" ");
  for(i=0; i<=word.length; i++) {
    return str.indexOf(word[i]) !== -1;
  }
}


function filterFromDS1() {
  const result =  _.filter(dataSource1, (item) => {
      return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
  });
  return result;
}


function filterFromDS2() {
  const result =  _.filter(dataSource2, (item) => {
      return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
  });
  return result;
}

searchResult['first'] = filterFromDS1();
searchResult['second'] = filterFromDS2();

console.log(searchResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the words to a RegExp (with the `i` flag - ignore case) and use `RegExp.test()` to find if the word is contained in the `product_name`:

```js
// takes a criteria, converts to regex, and returns a filter function
const filterByCriteria = (searchCriteria) => {
  const searchRegex = new RegExp(_.words(searchCriteria).join('|'), 'i');
  
  // the filtering functions expects a data souce and filters it
  return (ds) => ds.filter(o => searchRegex.test(o.product_name));
};

/** Usage: **/

var dataSource1 = [{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001","product_name":"sildenafil citrate","supplier":"Wisozk Inc","quantity":261,"unit_cost":"$10.47"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002","product_name":"Mountain Juniperus ashei","supplier":"Keebler-Hilpert","quantity":292,"unit_cost":"$8.74"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003","product_name":"Sample HBr","supplier":"Schmitt-Weissnat","quantity":211,"unit_cost":"$20.53"}];

var dataSource2 = [{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d90000021","product_name":"Hybrid product","supplier":"Wisozk Inc","quantity":261,"unit_cost":"$10.47"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d90000022","product_name":"Mountain Sample Juniperus ashei","supplier":"Keebler-Hilpert","quantity":292,"unit_cost":"$8.74"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d90000033","product_name":"Dextromathorphan HBr","supplier":"Schmitt-Weissnat","quantity":211,"unit_cost":"$20.53"}];

const searchCriteria = 'sample hybrid';

const filterDs = filterByCriteria(searchCriteria);

const searchResult = {
  first: filterDs(dataSource1),
  second: filterDs(dataSource2),
};

console.log(searchResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The problem in your code is the `compareEachWord()` function that returns immediately. Since you want the function to only return immediately if the result is `true`, and iterate to the end if not, you can use `Array.some()`:

```js
var dataSource1 = [{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001","product_name":"sildenafil citrate","supplier":"Wisozk Inc","quantity":261,"unit_cost":"$10.47"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002","product_name":"Mountain Juniperus ashei","supplier":"Keebler-Hilpert","quantity":292,"unit_cost":"$8.74"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003","product_name":"Sample HBr","supplier":"Schmitt-Weissnat","quantity":211,"unit_cost":"$20.53"}];

var dataSource2 = [{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d90000021","product_name":"Hybrid product","supplier":"Wisozk Inc","quantity":261,"unit_cost":"$10.47"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d90000022","product_name":"Mountain Sample Juniperus ashei","supplier":"Keebler-Hilpert","quantity":292,"unit_cost":"$8.74"},{"_id":"5968dd23fc13ae04d90000033","product_name":"Dextromathorphan HBr","supplier":"Schmitt-Weissnat","quantity":211,"unit_cost":"$20.53"}];

const searchCriteria = 'sample hybrid';
const searchResult = {};
function compareEachWord(str, searchCriteria) {
  var word = searchCriteria.split(" ");
  
  return word.some(w => str.includes(w));
}


function filterFromDS1() {
  const result =  _.filter(dataSource1, (item) => {
      return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
  });
  return result;
}


function filterFromDS2() {
  const result =  _.filter(dataSource2, (item) => {
      return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
  });
  return result;
}

searchResult['first'] = filterFromDS1();
searchResult['second'] = filterFromDS2();

console.log(searchResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `searchResult` is array. Try change it to object.

```
searchResult = {};
```

You would get a correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in compareEachWord

```
  for(i=0; i<=word.length; i++) {
    return str.indexOf(word[i]) !== -1;
  }
```

The return statement is stopping the loop. You should use an aux variable to compare all the words

```
 var hasWord = false;
 for(i=0; i<=word.length; i++) {
    hasWord = (hasWord || str.indexOf(word[i]) !== -1);
  }
 return hasWord;
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems.  The first is what `parndepu` identified, which is that `searchResult` should be an object/hash.  The second is that your method `compareEachWord` will always return the result of the search for the first word in your search criteria, even if it is false.  It will never have chance to search for other criteria.

As a bonus, I refactored your method `filterFromDS` to be more DRY.

EDIT: more micro-optimizations, especially as you seem to be using ES6

```js
const dataSource1 = [{
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001",
  "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
  "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
  "quantity": 261,
  "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002",
  "product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
  "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
  "quantity": 292,
  "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003",

  "product_name": "Sample HBr",
  "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
  "quantity": 211,
  "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}];

const dataSource2 = [{
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000021",
  "product_name": "Hybrid product",
  "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
  "quantity": 261,
  "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000022",
 
  "product_name": "Mountain Sample Juniperus ashei",
  "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
  "quantity": 292,
  "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
  "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000033",
  
  "product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
  "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
  "quantity": 211,
  "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}];

const searchCriteria = 'sample hybrid';
const searchResult = {};

function compareEachWord(str, searchCriteria) {
  const words = searchCriteria.split(" ");
  let hit = false;
  words.forEach(word => {
      if (str.indexOf(word) !== -1) hit = true;
  });
  return hit;
}

function filterFromDS(source) {
  const result = _.filter(source, item => {
      return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
  });
  return result;
}

searchResult['first'] = filterFromDS(dataSource1);
searchResult['second'] = filterFromDS(dataSource2);

console.log(searchResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const _ = require('lodash')

var dataSource1 = [{
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001",
    "product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
    "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
    "quantity": 261,
    "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002",
    "product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
    "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
    "quantity": 292,
    "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003",

    "product_name": "Sample HBr",
    "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
    "quantity": 211,
    "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}];

var dataSource2 = [{
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000021",
    "product_name": "Hybrid product",
    "supplier": "Wisozk Inc",
    "quantity": 261,
    "unit_cost": "$10.47"
}, {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000022",

    "product_name": "Mountain Sample Juniperus ashei",
    "supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
    "quantity": 292,
    "unit_cost": "$8.74"
}, {
    "_id": "5968dd23fc13ae04d90000033",

    "product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
    "supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
    "quantity": 211,
    "unit_cost": "$20.53"
}];

const searchCriteria = 'sample hybrid';
const searchResult = [];
function compareEachWord(str, searchCriteria) {
    var sample = searchCriteria.split(" ")[0]
    var hybrid = searchCriteria.split(" ")[1]
    return (str.match(sample) || str.match(hybrid))
}


function filterFromDS1() {
    const result = _.filter(dataSource1, (item) => {
        return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
    });
    return result;
}

function filterFromDS2() {
    const result = _.filter(dataSource2, (item) => {
        return compareEachWord(_.toLower(item.product_name), searchCriteria);
    });
    return result;
}
searchResult['first'] = filterFromDS1();
searchResult['second'] = filterFromDS2();

console.log(searchResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

searchResult should be an obj in this case, and I think it's nicer if you just reuse functionality instead of creating a function for each object you search

```
function findTerm(arr, terms) {
  terms = terms.split(' ');

  return arr.filter( i => {
    const productTerms = i.product_name.toLowerCase().split(' ')
    for (let i = 0; i < productTerms.length; i++) {
      if (terms.includes(productTerms[i])) return true;
    }
  });
}
const searchCriteria = 'sample hybrid';
const searchResult = {};
searchResult['first'] = findTerm(dataSource1, searchCriteria);
searchResult['second'] = findTerm(dataSource2, searchCriteria);
```